# How do the logical operators and/or work?

Tags: functional-programming

Can someone explain to me how the `and` and `or` operators work in Lisp?

Let's say I have a function and I want to write a composition of conditional expressions of a function from four arguments

```
and4 (x1 x2 x3 x4)
```

and

```
or4 (x1 x2 x3 x4)
```

coinciding with functions `and` and `or` from four arguments, can someone explain to how I can relate them or come up with something like this below:

```
and4(1,1,1,1) => 1
and4(1,0,1,1) => 0
or4(1,1,1,1) => 1
or4(0,0,1,0) => 1
```

I'm just interested in a simple explanation of how to understand the `and` and `or` operators, or even an example.

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear to me. You should know that 0 isn't a falsy value in Common Lisp though. Only `nil` is falsy: `(and 1 1) ;=> 1  (and nil 1); => nil  (and 1 0) ;=> 0` does that help?

Comment: AND and OR are macros in Lisp, not regular functions.  See http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/faq/lisp_3.faq, section `[3-2]`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to start simple.

Assume that the number 1 is true, and 0 is false.

Here is a truth table for the logical AND operator (aka && in many programming languages)

```
a | b | a AND b
0 | 0 |    0
0 | 1 |    0
1 | 0 |    0
1 | 1 |    1
```

So, if a is true AND b is true, then a && b is true.

The OR operator works slightly differently
Here is a truth table for the logical OR operator (aka || in many programming languages)

```
a | b | a OR b
0 | 0 |   0
0 | 1 |   1
1 | 0 |   1
1 | 1 |   1
```

So, if a is true OR b is true, then a OR b is true.

The statements you listed above work in a similar way.

```
AND4 (x1 x2 x3 x4)
```

The above will return 1 (true) if and only if ALL of the variables are true;

```
OR4 (x1 x2 x3 x4)
```

The abvove will return 1 (true) if AT LEAST ONE of the variables are true;

Comment: In the description of OR4 at the end, it might be worth changing "if and only if ONE of the variables are true" to "if and only if AT LEAST ONE ..." or "if and only if ANY ...". The current description can be misread as if you mean "EXACTLY ONE".